# How to force treat MySQL Constraint Errors from Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, constraints

I have a Java Web Project that uses Hibernate and MySQL. I have trouble to treat exceptions like when i try to insert a new register at database with the same primary key (Intentionally)
i got the following error with a message box "Could not insert:...". But i don't want to shows directly to user this error, i want to treat when i call "Persisten.save()", but in my code it doesn't appears nothing wrong (for my ide, i threat all possible excepetions).

So how can i change (configuration/code) to force threat exceptions like that and change the message?!

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the Id already exists in the database before you try to persist it.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the code, but maybe you are catching your exeptions at the wrong place? But what's wrong with checking first?

Comment: It's because the code for saving is generic (Just below), if i check if the Id already exists i'll have to do always for specific cases (or am i wrong?)


`code`
public void Save(Object obj)  {
        sessao.save(obj);
}
`code`

Comment: i got the answer. I wasn't throwing specific exceptions to catch these kind of errors. Eg.:
`public void Save(Object obj) { 
try {
session.save(obj)
} Catch (Exception ex) {
 throw new SpecificException(ex);
} 
}`

thnx for helping.